# Making the title larger than the subsection-how to?

Tags: sectioning

I want to make the title larger than the subsection but when I use large it's still not larger than the subsection .
please what can I do to fix this ?

```
\begin{center} 
CHAPTER ONE\\
\vspace{5 pt} 
\title{\large{\textbf{GENERAL INTRODUCTION}}} 
\end{center} 
\section{BACKGROUND AND CONTEXT OF STUDY}
```

Comment: Use \Large or \Huge

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Why don't you  use a dedicated package like `titlesec`  to format chapter titles?